# Point GoDaddy DNS to other DNS master for new subdomain

Tags: dns, godaddy

I have a domain `domain1.com and` am creating a new subdomain `sub.domain1.com` and this subdomain has it's own DNS, NOT GoDaddy's DNS.  I manage `domain1.com` DNS in GoDaddy right now and need to tell it that anyone looking for `sub.domain1.com` should go to ip `y.y.y.y` (master) or ip `x.x.x.x` (backup/slave).

Is there a way to do this?

I am a little familiar with how the DNS for .com points to the masters on the internet but I just need the `domain1.com` to tell people where the master is for `sub.domain1.com`.

I think I know how to, roughly, do this in bind9, but needed a quick solution for how to do it on GoDaddy.

Comment: This should be migrated to webmasters.

Answer (score 1):

I think the subdomain has the same IP address as the main domain.  To get it to use a different DNS you have to create the subdomain then redirect??

Unless you can just set the new nameservers to point to the subdomain.

Here is some info
http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/delegate-subdomain-different-dns-160294.html

Answer (score 1):

that link is for using the DNS for the main domain.  I know I have cheated before and had corporate computers point to .domain1.com and I had that domain server point to domain1.com so that I could add lots of DNS entries and then people could point to my DNS instead(this was when someone decided that everything should be accessed by ip at one company and I kept forgetting the ips of things)

I however did not figure out if it was possible to have the main domain1.com tell everyone that ip xxxx was the master authoritative DNS for .domain1.com and all computers on that subdomain like computer1..domain1.com, etc. etc.

I am pretty sure godaddy can't do this as I talked to someone that knew bind a bit better and was asking how to do it in bind.
later,
Dean